# CSS Height 100% doesn't fill 100% of parent's height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a parent div of the height 250px. Then I have a couple of children and set their min-height to 100%. I can tell from the debugger that the selector is correct and selects the correct elements, but the height doesn't fill the height of the parent at all, and instead is the smallest as the content allows.

```css
:root {
        --poke-main: #e05e8e;
        --poke-secondary: #f5ecc5;
        --poke-tertiary: #b5255a;
    }

    .card {
        border-color: var(--poke-tertiary);
    }

    .poke_tab {
        border-radius: .25rem;
        background-color: var(--poke-main);
        color: var(--poke-secondary);
        min-height: 100%;
    }

    #carousel {
        min-height: 250px;
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .poke_container, .carousel-inner, .poke_tab, .poke_tab .card {
        min-height: 100%;  /* This doesn't work */
    }

    .poke_container .card {
        background-color: var(--poke-secondary);
        color: var(--poke-tertiary);
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carousel" class="col-lg-10" >

  <!-- Infobox -->
  <div class="poke_container">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <!-- Log Tab -->
      <div class="poke_tab p-2">
        <div class="card">

          test

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because parent elements don't have a defined height.

When you set min-height: 100% on an element, it will only take up the available height if its parent has a specific height set.

In your case, the parent elements like `.poke_container` and `.carousel-inner` don't have a defined height, so the `min-height: 100%` property doesn't work as expected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    :root {
      --poke-main: #e05e8e;
      --poke-secondary: #f5ecc5;
      --poke-tertiary: #b5255a;
    }

    #carousel {
      min-height: 250px;
      background-color: yellow;
      position: relative; /* Added */
    }

    .poke_container {
      position: absolute; /* Added */
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      display: flex;
    }

    .carousel-inner {
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
    }

    .poke_tab {
      border-radius: .25rem;
      background-color: var(--poke-main);
      color: var(--poke-secondary);
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
    }

    .poke_tab .card {
      background-color: var(--poke-secondary);
      color: var(--poke-tertiary);
      border-color: var(--poke-tertiary);
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%; /* Added */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="carousel" class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="poke_container">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="poke_tab p-2">
          <div class="card">
            test
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: im a bit confused on why the min-height on .poke-container doesn't work then though... it's parent is #carouself, which has the height set to 500px, so setting .poke-containers min-height too 100% should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: Hi @alex,  right, 
There might be some CSS rules or properties affecting the height calculation of the elements, overriding or conflicting with the min-height property. 

It's also worth noting that the behavior of min-height can sometimes be unpredictable, especially when dealing with nested elements and percentages.

Comment: Thank you! I'll mark the answer as correct. Unfortunately it doesn't work with my actual case, but that's on me. I thought the snippet was enough, but with the solution presented, other elements around the snippet break. I might have to submit another question for my case more specifically